Cauchy-Schwarz for double index
We know by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that this hold:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\right)^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2 .$$
Does this also hold
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}b_{ij}\right)^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}^2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k b_{ij}^2 ?$$

Cauchy-Schwarz is about scalar products,
$$
\langle A,B\rangle^2\le⟨A,A⟩⟨B,B⟩.
$$
It does not matter if the scalar product is the simple Euclidean one or a Frobenius scalar product
$$
⟨A,B⟩=trace(AB^T)=\sum_{(i,j)=(1,1)}^{(n,r)}a_{ij}b_{ij}.
$$
Or a more general scalar product with a weight matrix.

Yes, the second inequality is also true, but for a very simple reason: we can reindex the pairs $(i, j)$ as a single index $r$. Let $i$ denote the row and $j$ the column in this table, then $r$ is the $(i, j)$ entry, reading across rows first then down columns:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  & 1 & 2 & \cdots & k \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & k \\
2 & k+1 & k+2 & \cdots & 2k \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
n & (n-1)k+1 & (n-1)k+2 & \cdots & nk
\end{array}
$$
For instance, with $n = 3$ and $k = 4$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
3 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12  
\end{array}
$$
Can you write down an explicit formula formula for $r$ in terms of $(i, j)$. (This should be a bijection, i.e., one-to-one and onto.)

 $$ r = (i-1)k+j $$

Challenge. Can you write down the inverse formula for $(i, j)$ in terms of $r$?

 $$ \begin{cases} i = 1 + \Bigl\lfloor \dfrac{r}{k} \Bigr\rfloor \\[4pt] j = 1 + \bigl((r-1) \bmod k\bigr) \end{cases}  $$

